# Test service with Mockito for delete method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I tried to make a mockito test for service for my delete method.

this is my delete method in my **RestoranServiceImpl.java**

```
public void deleteRestoran(Long idRestoran) {
        RestoranModel restoran = getRestoranByIdRestoran(idRestoran).get();
        if(restoran.getListMenu().size()==0){
            restoranDb.delete(restoran);
        }else{
            UnsupportedOperationException unsupportedOperationException = new UnsupportedOperationException();
            throw unsupportedOperationException;
        }
    }
```

and this is my **restoranDb.java**

```
public interface RestoranDb extends JpaRepository<RestoranModel,Long> {
    Optional<RestoranModel> findByIdRestoran(Long idRestoran);
}
```

This is my delete method so far

```
@Test
    public void whenDleleteValidRestoranItShouldCallRestoranRepositoryDelete() {
        RestoranModel newRestoran = new RestoranModel();
        newRestoran.setIdRestoran((long) 1);
        newRestoran.setNama("mekdi");
        newRestoran.setAlamat("pacil");
        newRestoran.setNomorTelepon(14045);
        restoranService.addRestoran(newRestoran);
        verify(restoranDb, times(1)).save(newRestoran);
        System.out.println(restoranService.getRestoranList().size());
        when(restoranDb.findByIdRestoran((long)1).get()).thenReturn(newRestoran).thenReturn(null);
        restoranService.deleteRestoran(newRestoran.getIdRestoran());
        verify(restoranDb, times(1)).delete(newRestoran);
    }
```

When I try to run it, I got this error.

`java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`

I tried to look around for a solution, but I can't find the solution that works for me.

Comment: Did you run a debug process in order to find the exact location of this exception occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mocking the wrong method here, you should mock `RestoranDb.findByIdRestoran` method, not the `Optional.get` method

```java
when(restoranDb.findByIdRestoran((long)1).get()).thenReturn(newRestoran).thenReturn(null);
```

Should be

```java
when(restoranDb.findByIdRestoran((long)1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(newRestoran));
```